# JAVA mail IllegalAddress Address Not Found

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am using JAVA mail to trigger mails using SMTP protocol . The MimeMessageHelper function setTo() accepts a String array wherein I can pass multiple email ids . The issue that I am facing is IllegalAddress Exception wherein one of the email ids turns out to be invalid since the person left organization and hence the email doesnt send to other valid emails , how do I handle this . If I am able to handle this , the mail can be triggered to other valid emails in the String array . Any pointers .

```
private MimeMessage constructMimeMessage(Mail mail, String type)
            throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        String html = "";
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(mail.getModel());
        if (type.equals(ALERT_MAIL)) {
            html = templateEngine.process("take1_email_template_alerts", context);
            helper.setTo(toEmailAddress);
        } else if (type.equals(GENERAL_MAIL)) {
            html = templateEngine.process("take1_email_template_general", context);
            helper.setTo(mail.getTo());
        }
        helper.setText(html, true);
        helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress, fromPersonalName));
        if (null != mail.getCc()) {
            helper.setCc(mail.getCc());
        }
        if (null != mail.getBcc()) {
            helper.setBcc(mail.getBcc());
        }
        if (null != mail.getReplyTo()) {
            helper.setReplyTo(mail.getReplyTo());
        }
        Optional.ofNullable(mail.getAttachments()).map(Collection::parallelStream).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
                .forEach(f -> addAttachment(helper, f));
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code snippet with the thrown exception along the line.

Comment: @tmarwen Added code snippet.